# Given two strings S and T, find length of the shortest subsequence in S which is not a subsequence in T

Tags: dynamic-programming

here m and n are length of string s and t. if (n == 0){
return 1;
}
if(m==0)
return INT_MAX;

please explain me the base case of this problem

Answer (score 0):

If the length of `T` is zero (`n == 0`), one character from `S` would be enough to qualify as a subsequence in `S` which is not a subsequence in `T`, hence:

```
if (n == 0)
  return 1;
```

And if we have an empty string for `S` (`m == 0`), we would need an infinity of it to generate a subsequence not in `T`, hence:

```
if (m==0)
  return INT_MAX;
```

(The assignment to infinity or largest machine number may have a practical application to deter the algorithm from this branch, but could also be implemented more conceptually as a flag.)